# Man Wearing slik shirt for a day

Tags: clothing

So I am graduating high school this year and for graduating day the special dress or uniform is decided by the principal . The cloth selected is slik and I know that it is prohibited to wear slik for men.
Could I wear it for that day and throw it away ?
The school does allow any other dress because they want to maintain uniformity .
So what should I do ?

Comment: I just wonder, just as a thought experiment, how your school masters would react if (don't do it)! you would be wearing a silk tie in the colors of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGBT ?!!!?

Comment: Would you still be graduated if you miss this special celebration?